# Google Sheets Script to duplicate data foreach country code

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a list of products with their attributes. Example column names are:

id, availability, condition, description, title, price, sale_price

In another sheet "cheat" I have a list of country codes like, FR and DE.

For each of those country codes I want to duplicate the product data and for each of those duplications add the country code in and "override" named column.

Here is a link to an example doc:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kkcpovmWAcqa3hRBmsw-8g3R1FKIUfNqD5BF6tI4egI/edit?usp=sharing

Any help here is appreciated as I'm struggling to even get started.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your sample doc sheet and came up with this method below:

**Recommendation**

I have created a script with custom function named `showResult()`:

```
function showResult() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var products = ss.getSheetByName('products'); //Gets all data on 'products' sheet
  var cheat = ss.getSheetByName('cheat'); //Gets all data on 'cheat' sheet
  var row = products.getDataRange().getNumRows(); //Counts current # of rows on 'products' sheet
  var cheatRow = cheat.getDataRange().getNumRows(); //Counts current # of rows on 'cheat' sheet
  var finalResult = [[products.getRange(1,1).getValue().toString(), //Initalize the column titles first on the finalResult array
                  products.getRange(1,2).getValue().toString(),
                  products.getRange(1,3).getValue().toString(),
                  products.getRange(1,4).getValue().toString(),
                  products.getRange(1,5).getValue().toString(),
                  'override']]; //Adds the 'override' column
  for(var i=2; i<=cheatRow; i++){ //First loop to get each country codes
      for(var x=2; x<=row; x++){ //Final loop to add each country codes to the each copy of grouped product values
      finalResult.push([products.getRange(x,1).getValue().toString(),
                    products.getRange(x,2).getValue().toString(),
                    products.getRange(x,3).getValue().toString(),
                    products.getRange(x,4).getValue().toString(),
                    products.getRange(x,5).getValue().toString(),
                    cheat.getRange(i,1).getValue()
                    ]);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('output').clear().getRange(1, 1, finalResult.length, finalResult[0].length).setValues(finalResult);
}

function onOpen() { //[Optional] Added a custom menu to manually to refresh your 'output' sheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Refresh output sheet')
      .addItem('Refresh', 'showResult')
      .addToUi();
}
```

This script will get all data from 'products' sheet (contains 5 columns):

[image]

Then, the script will start adding each country codes from 'cheat' sheet, as seen below, to every group of data from the 'products' sheet:

[image]

To run the script, you can click the "Refresh output sheet > Refresh" menu on your Spreadsheet:

[image]

To be able to dynamically update your 'output' sheet, you need to create a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) on the Apps Script editor, like this one that I've created to run the `showResult()` every 1 minute:

[image]

**RESULT**

On the 'output' sheet, this will be the result:

[image]

If there's a new 'product' data, it will be updated to the 'output' sheet as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, just trying this but hitting max execution time for the full sheet.

I have searched this and going to try an interation with your script.

Thank you very much.